# Could Not load Nib in bundle

Tags: nib, xcode8.2

I have not been able to upload a Nib to my table view, this problem happened with other application I was working on as well, even though I did have some NIb's files working just fine. I have even reinstall Xcode trying to fix the problem. I am register my Nib as follows

```
let test = "test"

let cellNib = UINib(nibName: test, bundle: nil)
tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: test) 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: test, for:indexPath) as! testCell //after this function is called I get a crash 
    return cell
}
```

This is part of the message I get from the crash, I do not know if is useful.

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in     bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'tests''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010afdab0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107b98141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b043625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000108b59b24 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 501
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001088ac567 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 402
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001088aca4b -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 71
    6   Chaol                               0x000000010759ebe9 _TFC5Chaol23QuestionsViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 153

My .XIB file appears on copy bundle resources.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the nib file is not added to your target.
Try those steps:

1. In Project > Target > Build Phases

   expand Copy Bundle Resources

   click + button and add the required NIB file.

   Clean your build by Shift+Cmd+K, then run.
2. In your .xib file

   click on File Inspector

   in Target Membership section, select the target you are using
3. Also, double check the spelling of your nib name.

Comment: I definitely tried that that, it did not work. I have created everything programmatically now.

Comment: It inspired me how to find out what is wrong - during renaming xib lost its reference. I needed to add it once again. Fun fact: git didn't spot it.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzpyrka it's wired that git didn't spot it. Usually the changes are in your ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.